# Procedure or function Proc_PIP_Employee has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am getting error

> Procedure or function Proc_PIP_Employee has too many arguments specified

when trying to call procedure `Proc_PIP_Employee` from C# code. The count of parameters checked and those are same. Also datatypes are same. Even after that getting the same error.

C# code is

```
public int Add_Record(Employee emp)
{
    try
    {
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)                
            con.Open();               

        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            SqlParameter RETURN_VALUE_OUTPUT = new SqlParameter();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "dbo.Proc_PIP_Employee";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Flag", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Empid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emp.Name ;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Designation", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emp.Designation;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Department", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emp.Department;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateofJoin", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = emp.Dateofjoin;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emp.Phone;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Isactive", SqlDbType.Int).Value = emp.IsActive;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LoginUser", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "admin";

            RETURN_VALUE_OUTPUT = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnId",SqlDbType.Int);
            RETURN_VALUE_OUTPUT.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            ReturnID = Convert.ToInt32(RETURN_VALUE_OUTPUT.Value.ToString());
        }             
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
    }

    return ReturnID;
}
```

The stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_PIP_Employee]
    @Flag int,
    @Empid int,
    @Name varchar(500),
    @Designation varchar(200),
    @Department varchar(200),
    @DateofJoin datetime,
    @Phone varchar(3000),
    @Isactive int,
    @LoginUser nvarchar(500)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON ;

    DECLARE @errorMessage VarChar(8000), 
            @errorSeverity Int,
            @errorState Int,
            @ReturnId Int,
            @AlCode varchar(50),
            @AlDesc varchar(1000),
            @AlOp varchar(50),
            @AlStatus varchar(50)

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        IF (@Flag = 1)
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.PIP_Employee 
                       GROUP BY Name, Phone
```

Comment: Seems like you're confusing the `RETURN` value and `OUTPUT` parameters. The former is designed to return a status code for the SP's success; `0` meaning success anything else meaning failure (and normally that `RETURN` value is the error number). An `OUTPUT` parameter can be any scalar data type, and is design to return something other than the success of the SP.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding an `OUTPUT` parameter for this stored procedure to your C# code - but there's no `@ReturnId OUTPUT` parameter in your stored procedure interface:

```
SqlParameter RETURN_VALUE_OUTPUT = new SqlParameter();
RETURN_VALUE_OUTPUT = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnId",SqlDbType.Int);
RETURN_VALUE_OUTPUT.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

If you attempted to capture the **return** value - then use `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` instead

```
SqlParameter RETURN_VALUE_OUTPUT = new SqlParameter();
RETURN_VALUE_OUTPUT = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnId",SqlDbType.Int);
RETURN_VALUE_OUTPUT.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

Comment: after this am getting another error like Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.
A transaction that was started in a MARS batch is still active at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back.

Comment: @Ann: that must be something in the body of the stored procedure - which you haven't posted here --> that's a totally new question, really. The invocation now works - right? So this answer here **is** the solution for your problem - right?